# GeoNetwork record intermittently displays as template rather than record information

Tags: geonetwork

We've seen and also had reported to us by our users an intermittent display of the template instead of the dataset record from our GeoNetwork data catalogue. See below: [image: screenshot of display issue]

We are using GeoNetwork version 3.4.2.

Refreshing the webpage usually returns the record but on returning to the same record later the template page being displayed again intermittently. Our users don't always realise that refreshing will usually display the record correctly.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, were you able to resolve the issue and how did you carry out the fix?

Any help or pointers welcome.

Comment: It's been a long time since I managed a geonetwork catalog and never saw this so can't answer, just suggest you review the server logs and the browsers developer tools console for any obvious errors when the issue occurs.